# Is adding this hierarchically class an antipattern

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, solid-principles, anti-patterns

I had some classes like this:

```
+---+             +---+
| L | ---uses---> | D |
+---+             +---+
  |               +---+
inherit ----<---- | V |
  |        +---+  +---+
  +---<--- | C |
           +---+
```

Let's say; class `L` is an abstract class, and `V` and `C` inherits from it. And `L` have a property of class `D`. - sorry for my bad drawing and also English-

Now, I need to add a new class -`RA`- that has a property of class `D` and class `V` should have a property of class `RA`, But I also need to get property from objects of class `L` So `V`. In my mind something like this:

```
+---+           +---+           +----+
| L | --uses--> | D | <--uses-- | RA |
+---+           +---+           +----+
  |              +---+            |
inherit ----<----| V | --uses-->--+
  |       +---+  +---+
  +---<---| C |
          +---+
```

I'm not sure!; But it seems to me like an anti-pattern or breaker of LSP -of SOLID principle- somehow!, But I can't figure it out.

Is my new diagram an anti-pattern? or is there a better way to design this situation?

Note that classes like `D`, `V`, `C` and `RA` can instantiate.
And I meant that usage of property of class `D` is now hierarchically in class `V`.

**Edit:**
Imagine that I use an interface -`IGFP`- that returned a `string` value by using `D` property in `L` so in `V` and `C`, now in `V` I need to override it by using `RA` instead of `D`.
In C# classes are:

```
public abstract class L : VOBase<L>, IGFP {
    public virtual D D { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string GFP => $"{D.GFP}/{Name}";        // Here I use D property that I think breaks LSP
}

public class C : L {
    public C (D d, string name) {
        D = d;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class V : L {
    public V (RA ra, string name) {
        RA = ra;
        Name = name;
        D = ra.D;
    }
    public RA RA { get; private set; }
    public override string GFP => $"{RA.GFP}/{Name}";  // Here I should override GFP to use RA instead of D
}

public class D : VOBase<D>, IGFP {
    public D (U u, string name) {
        U = u;
        Name = name;
    }
    public U U { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string GFP => $"{U.GFP}/{Name}";
}

public class RA : VOBase<RA>, IGFP {
    public RA (D d, string name) {
        D = d;
        Name = name;
    }
    public D D { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string GFP => $"{D.GFP}/{Name}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure whatever you are smelling isn't really described by this question.

But let me attempt to break it down.

First `D` is only used by two other classes. Nothing wrong with that. What makes `D` any different from both classes referencing a class like `String`? So let's remove it from the diagram:

```
+---+                           +----+
| L |                           | RA |
+---+                           +----+
  |              +---+            |
inherit ----<----| V | --uses-->--+
  |       +---+  +---+
  +---<---| C |
          +---+
```

Now, `RA` is only used, why is that any different from using a class like `String` or `D`, let's remove it from the diagram:

```
+---+
| L |
+---+
  |              +---+            
inherit ----<----| V | 
  |       +---+  +---+
  +---<---| C |
          +---+
```

So now we have a very simple diagram that doesn't demonstrate any issues.

So, no, your diagram doesn't indicate any anti pattern. But that's not to say it's not one, just that the diagram doesn't contain enough information. I know you have tried to explain in English, but English is ambiguous. Only seeing an actual code example of how these classes interact would allow people to identify anti-patterns or improvements.

Comment: tnx for your answer, I think you mean that there isn't any anti-pattern, I'll add some codes here to make more sense ;).

Comment: I sort of said that: "your diagram doesn't indicate any anti pattern"

Comment: I've done some simplification, does the code still look wrong to you?

Comment: Now `GFP` of `V` will miss `RA.Name`! instead of `UName/DName/RAName/VName` I'll have `UName/DName/VName` - ;).

Comment: Oh right. It is very hard to follow with these names, repeated names and very similar method bodies.